# Robots.txt in the root directory, will that override the Meta tag or will the Meta tag override the robots.txt file?

Tags: meta-tags, robots.txt, meta

I do not want any search engines from indexing my website, so I put robots.txt in the root directory; will that override the Meta tag or will the Meta tag override the robots.txt file?

The reason for asking this question is that some pages may have the Meta tag telling robots to index, follow, however I have moved the site to a sub-domain name witch I am still tweaking the site before it’s it goes live to replace the old site and I do not want to have to remove all of the Meta tag telling robots to index, follow then when the site is ready have to replace the Meta tag telling robots to index, follow so I’m think that the robots.txt is the quickest, easiest and does not alter the site other than tell robots not to index, follow if that’s what I in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the robots.txt disallows crawling the directory that contains the document, then presumably they won't ever get to the document, so there's no issue.

If there are "follow" attributes in an HTML link, the robot will queue those URLs for crawling, but then when it actually tries to crawl it will see the block in robots.txt and not crawl.

The short answer is: robots.txt will prevent a well-behaved crawler from following a link, regardless of where it got that link or what attributes were associated with that link when it was found.